# Use Algrebraic Operation in Cytoscape Selector Style Sheet

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I would like to use algebraic operations in order to be more flexible in the Cytoscape style sheet. My first trial was

```
    {
        selector: 'node',
        style: {
            'content': 'data(d0)',
            'width': 'data(d1)*10 -5', /*Here*/
            'height': 'data(d1)/10 +5' /*Here*/
        }
    },
```

However, it turn out to be invalid. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using functions for this feature:

```
{
    selector: 'node',
    style: {
        'content': 'data(d0)',
        'width': function (node) {
            return (node.data().di * 10) - 5;
        },
        'height': function (node) {
            return (node.data().di / 10) + 5;
        }
    }
}
```